# CSV parser java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java

```
    public class ReadCSV {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<CsvParserPojo> csvParserPojoList = getCsv("C:\\Users\\test\\Desktop\\csv\\Test.csv");
        for (CsvParserPojo csvParserPojo:csvParserPojoList){
            System.out.println(csvParserPojo);
        }
    }
    private static List<CsvParserPojo> getCsv(String file) {
        List<CsvParserPojo> csvParserPojoList = new ArrayList<>();
        Path pathToFile = Paths.get(file);
        try(BufferedReader br = Files.newBufferedReader(pathToFile)) {
            String row = br.readLine();
            while (row!=null){
                String [] attributes = row.split(".");
                CsvParserPojo csvParserPojo = getOneCsv(attributes);
                csvParserPojoList.add(csvParserPojo);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return  csvParserPojoList;
    }
    private static CsvParserPojo getOneCsv(String[] attributes) {
        double total_Gain = Double.parseDouble(attributes[0]);
        String uid = attributes[1];
        double t1 = Double.parseDouble(attributes[2]);
        double t2 = Double.parseDouble(attributes[3]);
        double t3 = Double.parseDouble(attributes[4]);
        double t4 = Double.parseDouble(attributes[5]);
        double przep_ywom_v = Double.parseDouble(attributes[6]);
        boolean connectionControll = Boolean.parseBoolean(attributes[7]);
        CsvParserPojo csvParserPojo = new CsvParserPojo(total_Gain,uid,t1,t2,t3,t4,przep_ywom_v,connectionControll);
        return  csvParserPojo;
    }
}
```

I have problem with

```
"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0
    at org.example.ReadCSV.getOneCsv(ReadCSV.java:34)
    at org.example.ReadCSV.getCsv(ReadCSV.java:25)
    at org.example.ReadCSV.main(ReadCSV.java:13)"
```

Comment: It's because the `attributes` in your `getOneCsv` function is empty.

Comment: the error says that there is no element in some array (I guess `String[] attributes` of getOneCsv, check whatever is in line 34 because the error is in `ReadCSV.java:34` ), so please check it.

Answer (score 2):

Calling `row.split(".")` is the problem.

[`String.split()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) takes a regular expression and `.` means "any character", so it will split on literally any character and `split` will discard any trailing empty elements, which will mean the resulting array of that call is always empty, independent of the value of `row`.

If you want to split on a literal `.` character you'll need to escape it:

```
String[] attributes = row.split("\\.");
```

The double `\` is because you need to escape the backslash for strings in general. Note that the C in CSV stands for comma, so splitting on `.` is probably not intended anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You call `getOneCsv(String[] attributes)` with an empty array.
Resulting on

```java
double total_Gain = Double.parseDouble(attributes[0]);
```

having no element at `attributes[0]` which raises an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` because `Index 0` is `out of bounds` in an array of `length 0`